# Angular 17 doesn't accept paths with dots (.) in development environment, it just throws a 404 error straight up

Tags: angular

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'foo.bar', component: ListComponent },
    { path: 'foobar', component: ListComponent },
```

`example.com/foobar` works well and `example.com/foo.bar` return 404

It works fine in the production environment but only appears on the local development page when using `ng serve`. This makes it a bit challenging for me to debug specific url parameters.

Regarding this 404 error, even if the page I'm trying to access isn't configured in the `routes`, it should redirect to the default `**` or `/` destination instead of going straight to a 404.

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.1:4200/foo.bar

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2024 02:52:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Content-Length: 0
```

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.1:4200/foobar

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2024 02:52:13 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Content-Length: 891

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
                <script type="module" src="/openai/@vite/client"></script>
...
```

Comment: Because using a `.` in a URL is basically another domain... You can't use this URL structure on your own site... What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: `example.com/foo.php` is a very common practice

Comment: Using a dot in a path part of URL is a completely valid use case and is commonly used, e.g. for versioning of APIs or docs `example.com/docs/2.1.1/changes`. Please read the according [specs](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt). And it should work in Angular - I know it used to work in the past at least. How are you hosting it? Maybe it's an issue with your web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular CLI 17 uses new [application](https://angular.io/guide/esbuild) builder by default.

That means that you're running your code with combination of esbuild and vite.

It was a known issue with vite and should be fixed starting with `@angular/cli@17.1.0-next.0`.

Related issues:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26320#issuecomment-1805619487
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26551